# Keeping filenames when reading multiple csv files

Tags: python-3.x

I'm reading in multiple csvs, each with data about an individual stock.  I'm using the code below to read them all in separately for comparison.  The data is fine to work with, but I lost the name of the csv file when reading it in. So I don't know which dataframe is which stock in python.  Is there a way to record or label each dataframe with the name of the csv file?

```
path =r'/Users/Name/Desktop/STAT 3250 Data Analysis With Python/Stocks'
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

allsep = []
for filename in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None)
    allsep.append(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary.

```
path =r'/Users/Name/Desktop/STAT 3250 Data Analysis With Python/Stocks'
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

allsep = {}
for filename in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None)
    allsep[filename] = df
```

You can access the DF for each file using the filename:

```
allsep['somefile.csv']
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?:

```
path =r'/Users/Name/Desktop/STAT 3250 Data Analysis With Python/Stocks'
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

allsep = []
for filename in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None)
    allsep.append((df,filename))
```

Each file in the list is now a tuple with the filename it corresponds to. if you want to be able to be able to reference the dataframe itself for the filename, you vould just add it as an attribute, and reference that later:

```
path =r'/Users/Name/Desktop/STAT 3250 Data Analysis With Python/Stocks'
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

allsep = []
for filename in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None)
    df.name = filename
    allsep.append()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an attribute (e.g., `filename`) to every Dataframe instance.

```
path =r'/Users/Name/Desktop/STAT 3250 Data Analysis With Python/Stocks'
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

allsep = []
for filename in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None)
    df.filename = filename
    allsep.append(df)
```

Once you have added this attribute, you can use it as a normal attribute. For example if you need a list with all filenames, than you can do something like this:

```
filenames = list(map(getattr, allsep, ['filename']*len(allsep)))
```

Or you can access to the attribute in the usual way: `df.filename`.